# (Vue.JS) Deleting item from Vue tree object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have tree object of posts:

```
{'id': 1,
 'body': 'test1',
 'child': {
      'id': 2,
      'body': 'test2',
      'child': {
          'id': 3,
          'body': 'test2',
         }
     }
}
```

How to delete item and his childs with the particular ID withoud losing structure?

I'm using Vue.JS and got this recursive function, but **it works only in the case with setTimeout function**:

```
remove(index) {
     let result = this.filter(this.posts, index);
     this.posts = [];
     setTimeout(() => {
         this.posts = result;
     }, 3000);
},

filter(data, id) {
     var result = data.filter(o => {
     if (o.child) o.child = this.filter(o.child, id);
         return o.id != id;
     })
     return result;

},
```

Without setTimemout VueJS doesn't rerender filtered array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make the live demo for this ? I think `computed` result will do this

Comment: @user2486 oh sorry for waiting.

Comment: @user2486 i'm confused. i made a demo, but it works fine
https://jsfiddle.net/craaakk/bkarwnpr/
i'm going to look for my mistake. sorry about that

Comment: @user2486 okay. object from my example works fine but there is no the such result with my project. object that fetches via my api so big and seems like Vue cannot parse it in the right way...